# Compactness of the convolution integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, integral-operators

I have a problem in an exercise and I would be grateful for hints. I have to show that if $  f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the integral operator $$\begin{array}{rcl} T_f: L^p(\Omega)& \to& L^p(\Omega) \\ g &\mapsto&  f *g \end{array}$$ is compact for all $1\leq p < \infty $, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here, $f*g$ denotes the convolution $$(f*g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)g(x-y) dy.$$

My attemp: By the definition of a [compact operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator), we have to show, that the image of the unit ball in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ under $T_f$ is relatively compact in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now, by the [Fréchet–Kolmogorov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_theorem), I have to show the equicontinuity and equitightness, i.e., for all $g \in B_1(L^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$ the following holds
$$\begin{array}{rrcll} (\text{equicontinuity})& \lim_{|h|\to 0} ||\tau_hT_fg-T_fg||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}&=&0 & \text{uniformly}, \\ (\text{equitightness})&\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{|x|>r} |T_fg|^p&=&0& \text{uniformly}.  \end{array}$$
Here, $\tau_hu(x)=u(x-h)$ denotes the translation of $u$. For the first property it remains to show
$$\begin{array}{rcl} \lim_{|h|\to 0} ||\tau_hT_fg-T_fg||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}&=& \lim_{|h|\to 0}  \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)(g(x-h-y)-g(x-y))\, dy\right|^p \, dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \overset{?}{=} 0.   \end{array}$$
But here, I am struggeling with the theory. How can I show that this integral converges to $0$ for $|h|\to 0$? And for the second property, equitightness, I am completely clueless.

Comment: Translation is continuous on $L^p$, that is, $\|\tau_h g - g\|_{L^p} \to 0$ for $|h|\to 0$. Not sure, how this helps.

Comment: The continuous functions with compact supports are dense in $L^1.$ Let $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ norm, where $f_n\in C_c.$ Then $T_{f_n} \to T_f$ with respect to the operator norm on $L^p.$ Hence it suffices to show that $T_f$ is compact. for $f\in C_c.$ Equicontinuity follows from uniform continuity of $f.$

Comment: The operator is not compact unless $f =0$.

Comment: The spectrum of $T_f$ can be determined by the range of the Fourier transform of $f.$